# When will managed container services (AKS) be available on Azure Government?

Tags: azure, azure-gov

[This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuregov/2018/01/08/trends-in-government-software-developers/) from January 2018 states that AKS will be coming to Azure Government soon.  Do we know of a target delivery date?

[An older post](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/558487-azure-government/suggestions/20475739-azure-container-service-acs-aks-in-azure-gover) references a target of Q3, but the newer post was more vague.

Comment: AKS uses Kubernetes, which is why the tag was originally added.  Is there a reason I should not use that tag for this question?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a matter for azure support, not SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The latest and most accurate update on timing of feature availability in Azure Government is always the [Azure Government feedback forum](https://aka.ms/azuregovfeedback)**.

As such, you should go by the date posted in the [Azure Container Service (ACS/AKS) in Azure Government](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/558487-azure-government/suggestions/20475739-azure-container-service-acs-aks-in-azure-gover) feedback entry which at this point in time is preview in CY18Q3. Vote for the feedback entry so that you get updates as they become available.

Side note: The [Trends in Government Software Developers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuregov/2018/01/08/trends-in-government-software-developers/) article dates back to January 2018 whereas the latest response to the  dates back to February 2018.

Comment: Thanks!  I missed that date line.